# Capistrano 3.0 assets:precompile failed on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I have tried several ways to deploy to my server using Capistrano v3 but its has failed with the following error;
I have tried precompiling locally but it has failed.

```
DEBUG [4ec78ee3] Command: cd /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140101221937 && bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /usr/local/bin/ruby /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    undefined method `fetch' for false:FalseClass
```

My deploy file looks like this below;

```
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "bundle exec rake"

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
       execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
       within release_path do
         execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
       end
    end
  end

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

end
```

Here is a detailed trace;

```
INFO [4ec78ee3] Running bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production on 208.68.39.56
DEBUG [4ec78ee3] Command: cd /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140101221937 && bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /usr/local/bin/ruby /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    undefined method `fetch' for false:FalseClass
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:35:in `resolve_string_connection'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140101221937/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    Tasks: TOP => environment
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/bin/ruby /var/www/html/webapp/s...]
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    /var/www/html/webapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
DEBUG [4ec78ee3]    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have run `cap production deploy:compile_assets`

and got this;
cap aborted!

```
if test ! -d /var/www/html/webapp/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/html/webapp/current'" 1>&2; false; fi stdout: Nothing written
if test ! -d /var/www/html/webapp/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/html/webapp/current'" 1>&2; false; fi stderr: Nothing written
```

Remember, its still an empty file.

Comment: Can you get a better stack trace?  What file does the error `undefined method 'fetch' for false:FalseClass` occur in?  Btw, Capistrano 3 tends to give cryptic error messages when an expected Capistrano variable is not defined, and fetch is one way to get Capistrano variables.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, i have added a detailed trace..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but is the first step in troubleshooting.

First, go to the server and run the exact same command that Capistrano is running to make sure you can reproduce the exact same error.  This puts Capistrano out of the picture and now the bug becomes just something about Rails and your configuration of it.

Here is the line that is raising the error:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb#L35

The error message tells us that `configurations` is false, but the code is expecting it to be some object that responds to `fetch` (probably a hash).  The problem is that the `@configurations` instance variable inside this `ActiveRecord::Base::ConnectionSpecification::Resolver` got set to `false` erroneously.  Do you know why that might be happening?  I would check all the configuration files that have anything to do with the database connection and make sure they look OK.

If that does not help, the next step is to find out why that variable is getting set to `false`.  Well, if we look two lines lower in the stack trace, we can see how this Resolver object got created and used:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb#L129-130

That method is just calling `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` and passing it to the Resolver object.  So now the question becomes how did `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` get set to false?

**Edit 1:**

Here is the documentation and code for `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations`:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L341-369

It sounds like `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` is supposed to come from your database.yml file.  You should go to your server and look carefully at your database.yml file and see if it might somehow be read as false.  You should post that file here.

Comment: thank you... now i have another weird error, dont know if you can help. Deploy fails here `cd /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140102101731 && /usr/bin/env cp /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140102101731/public/assets/manifest*.json /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140102101731/assets_manifest_backup.json
` at the `deploy:assets:backup_manifest
`

Comment: This could be debugged using similar troubleshooting strategies to the ones I explained above.

Comment: i have tried similar methods...Whats most bothering is that in rails 3.2 manifest.yml exist not manifest.*json

Comment: I think manifest.yml is part of the Rails asset pipeline and the JSON files you see are part of Capistrano's asset tracking.  It is a bit tricky for Capistrano to know how to deploy, rollback, and cleanup Rails assets and those files are necessary for storing metadata about the assets.